# RayCast intersect on multimaterial

Tags: three.js

Is there any particular reason why raycast intersection fails when applying multimaterial (in my case LambertMaterial **with wireframe:true** + LambertMaterial with just color) on mesh?

If I apply "solid" material (means any material without wireframe:true) intersection works, if I apply multimaterial (solid+wire, or solid+solid), no intersection occurs.

Bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source for `THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject` you will see that it creates the multi-material effect by creating child meshes of a parent object.

You need to pass the recursive flag into `intersectObjects()` like so:

```
raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, true );
```

three.js r.63